# CA Siteminder and Node Express application

Tags: express, authentication, single-sign-on, siteminder

Is it possible to use CA Siteminder single sign on with a Node Express application?  Perhaps a custom agent could be created and called from custom middleware?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I haven't.

Comment: Mark, 3 Years Later I'm trying to do the same thing, Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, Sorry, I'm only now seeing this.